# Why links are not clickable with an image that is not 100% opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity

I created this little project to demonstrate my problem: https://codepen.io/jmdagenais/pen/bGegrEV

```css
.content {
    max-width: 450px;
}

.image-wrapper {
    height: 135px;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    opacity: 25%;
}

.button-section {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://agilewarrior.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/cirlce-illustrator.png?w=500&h=480">
    </div>

    <div class="button-section">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
        <a href="http://www.github.com" target="_blank">Github</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a similar situation on the website at my job. Links over an image that is not 100% opacity are not clickable.

If the opacity of the image is 100% the links are clickable.

Can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: Seems like a z-index issue. set wrapper and section to be position relative and give z index values. Seems weird you are not just using a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position your anchors (or a container thereof) with `position: relative` will resolve your issue, but it will also stop your anchors being faded by the opacity CSS rule. I'm unclear if that's an intention or a side effect, but you can easily tweak your opacity CSS if needed.

```css
.content {
    max-width: 450px;
}

.image-wrapper {
    height: 135px;
}

.image-wrapper img {
    opacity: 25%;
}

.button-section {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    /* opacity: 50% if you need */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://agilewarrior.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/cirlce-illustrator.png?w=500&h=480">
    </div>

    <div class="button-section">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
        <a href="http://www.github.com" target="_blank">Github</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The image is blocking your events. That's because of [the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). Elements with opacity below 1 are rendered after your other elements.

I would suggest to add `pointer-events: none;` to your image-wrapper class if you don't care interacting with it.

```
.image-wrapper {
    height: 135px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
a{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: z-index will not help here, because opacity overflows and messes with it as it is rendered last. Z-Index will not prevent the overflow. The Opacity will overflow after the z-index during rending making the z-index obsolete. By using the snippet editor you could have tested it on your own.